# C wait untill a message arrive on a socket

Tags: c, sockets

I want to build a program in which two processes exchange messages with each other using AF_UNIX socket. In particular, the client has a loop in which an array of 20 integers is created and waits for a random time and then sends the array to the server; the server has a loop in which it waits for an array of 20 integers to come and it prints the receiving data.

```
cilent:
int fd=CreateSocketClient();
int *a=calloc(20, sizeof(int));
int i, j;
while(1){
    for(i=0; i<20; i++)
        a[i]=rand()%20;
    j=rand()%1000
    Client_sleep(j);
    send(fd, a, 20, 0);
}


server:
 int fd=CreateSocketServer();
int *a=calloc(20, sizeof(int));
int ;
while(1){
    WaitForMessage(fd);
    recv(fd, a, 20, 0);
    for(i=0; i<20; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

The question is: how can I implement the WaitForMessage()function in the server? if the client sends two messages, one can be ignored by the server.

EDIT to focus on the problem, I did not show the functions to create a socket in client and server. The type is AF_UNIX.

Comment: Are you asking how to wait until exactly 20 "messages" arrive? It's not possible to deduce whether or not there are 20 "messages" present other than *trying to read from the socket*. `recv`, on blocking sockets, will block until it can read. So if you're using blocking sockets, execute `recv` on a loop until you read 20 bytes (or however many bytes you need to read for 20 "messages")

Comment: I suggest going through [beej's guide to network programming in C](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/pdf/bgnet_usl_c_1.pdf)

Comment: On what basis do you claim that the server is permitted to ignore messages?  Note that how you create the sockets matters for this purpose, so your decision to omit those details does not serve you well.

Answer (score 1):

For a single-client server with blocking sockets `WaitForMessage` is `recv` call. For a multi-client server with non-blocking sockets `WaitForMessage` is `select`, or `epoll`, or whatever your platform provides, see [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) for more details.

`recv`, however, must be called repeatedly to keep filling your receive buffer until it contains at least one complete message.

The receiver needs a way to detect a complete message, and the canonical ways are:

1. Each message is prefixed with a fixed-size header, which tells the exact message size to receive.
2. Each message is terminated with a sequences of bytes (e.g. `\r\n\r\n` for HTTP messages with no payload). Keep reading the socket until message terminating sequence is detected.